# WOW.js does not work on page reload

Tags: jquery, html, css, skrollr, wow.js

I am using WOW.js and skrollr to reveal some animations on my website.

I have a navbar with is located `370px` from the top of the viewport initially and while the page is being scrolled down and when the bottom of the navbar is `70px` from the top of the viewport stays on fixed position:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 navbar nopad wow slideInLeft animated" data-370-top="opacity:0.65;position:relative;" data-70-top-bottom="opacity:1;position:fixed;top:0px">
```

I also use the `slideInLeft` class of WOW.js to slide the navbar in.

The problem is that when the scrollbar is `370px` from the top of the screen and the page is reload the wow animation does not occur.

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the website is being tested on Chrome 47 and Mozilla 43

Comment: I guess you could use $(window).load() to load the animation?

Comment: I use new WOW().init to instanstiate the plugin..

Comment: then you could put that initiation inside a window load to make sure it's initiated when the page is loaded